# Convert from base6 to base64 in Bash

Tags: bash, base64

I don't know much programming and have tried to find an answer, but have trouble finding anything even related to base6.  I am trying to write a bash script to take a string of dice rolls and convert it to a base64 password.

I've tried

```
echo 13545142010250324013240412300102 |base64
```

but I get weird outputs such as

```
MTM1NDUxNDIwMTAyNTAzMjQwMTMyNDA0MTIzMDAxMDIK
```

or

```
MTM0MTIzNDM1MzQwMTIwNDMxMjQxCg==
```

which is not uniformly distributed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `base64` command expects binary input. Your base-6 string is not uniformly distributed on the set of characters that `base64` accepts, therefore the output will also follow a severely restricted distribution.

Comment: Is there a command to translate the b6 into the proper set?  I've tried to use echo "obase=2; ibase=6; <b6 string>" |bc |base64 and I still can't achieve an even distribution.  I don't understand how the distribution is uneven.  Would each b6 digit need to be converted to binary first and then passed though base64 one at a time?

Comment: The `echo "obase=2; ibase=6; <b6 string>" | bc` command restricts your input distribution even further, from 6 symbols to only 2. You want an even distribution on the 256 possible input symbols.

Perhaps try `obase=256` and process the output from `bc` using another tool, possibly your own script?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: convert your number in radix 64 using `bc` and then convert each "digit" of this number into a character:

```
#!/bin/bash

pool=( {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} + / )

shopt -s extglob

die() { (($#)) && printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }

[[ $1 = +([012345]) ]] || die "bad argument"

for i in $(BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<< "obase=${#pool[@]}; ibase=6; $1"); do
    printf '%s' "${pool[10#$i]}"
done
printf '\n'
```

I called this script `banana`, I `chmod +x banana` and then:

```
$ ./banana 13545142010250324013240412300102
HSr/X8Hn0oUGFG
```

You can safely change the elements of `pool`: modify, add or remove elements in there, the new radix is automatically taken into account, since we used `obase=${#pool[@]}`, **as long as there are at least 17 elements in `pool`.**

**Note.** I'm using `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` to disable `bc`'s output multi-line feature. If not available on your system, you'll have to handle trailing backslashes. The adaptation is straightforward and left as an exercise to the reader.